# Long running kthread and synchronize_net

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing an experimental driver that spawn a kernel thread. This thread is supposed to run for a long time. Since it performs some latency sensitive tasks, I do not want the thread to ever sleep. The thread runs a tight loop performing a certain task. I am okay with a CPU being held forever. I haven't disabled pre-emption and irqs yet, but plan to do that in the future.

This works fine so far. But when I try to call `dev_remove_pack` (which internally calls `synchronize_net`) in an ioctl, the call to `dev_remove_pack` gets stuck and I am forced to restart the system. This ioctl is also implemented as part of my driver.

To clarify, the call to `dev_remove_pack` happens on the thread that calls the ioctl not on the long running thread.

I have managed to fix the issue by making the long running kthread sleep once in a while, but it is not ideal.

In the busy loop that I have I added the following code that fixed it -

```
unsigned long long counter = 0;
while (1) { 
    // Busy loop logic
    ...
   
    counter++;
    if (counter % 10000000 == 0)
        msleep(1);
}
```

What is the reason for this issue? How can I properly address it without adding a sleep in the long running thread?

Comment: *"the call gets stuck"* - which exactly call gets stuck, from which code? Does this ioctl implemented in your kernel module? Please, describe a bit more detailed. *"fix the issue"* - please post the code snippet where you fixed it.

Comment: @red0ct I have edited the question to clarify, but to answer your question the call to `dev_remove_pack` gets stuck. Yes, this ioctl is also a part of my device driver. Code snippet for the "fix" added to the question

Comment: What happens if you call `schedule()` instead of `msleep(1)`?